# How can a Looking-Glass Hill be a Valley?

Tags: lewis-carroll, through-the-looking-glass

In Chapter 2 of *Through the Looking-Glass*, Alice and the Red Queen find themselves in a series of arguments, including one to do with the nature of hills and valleys. Alice begins this particular argument by mentioning the word “hill”:

> “...I thought I’d try to find my way to the top of that hill—-”
>
> “When you say ‘hill,’” the Red Queen interrupted, ”I could show you hills, in comparison with which you’d call that a valley.”

Here, a logical Alice disagrees strongly with the Red Queen:

> “No, I shouldn’t,” said Alice, surprised into contradicting her at last: “a hill can’t be a valley, you know. That would be nonsense—”

Can a simple argument be constructed to make sense of the Red Queen’s “hills” and valley comparison?

Answer (score 3):

It appears the Red Queen is boasting or simply trying to show off. Just before the conversation around hills and valleys the Red Queen and Alice have this exchange:

> “I only wanted to see what the garden was like, your Majesty—”
>
> “That’s right,” said the Queen, patting her on the head, which Alice didn’t like at all, “though, when you say ‘garden,’—*I’ve* seen gardens, compared with which this would be a wilderness.”
>
> <sup>Through the Looking-Glass - Chapter II. The Garden of Live Flowers</sup>

The emphasis on the "I" above is taken directly from the source material, and seems to imply the Red Queen is trying to show off that while this might be a nice garden to Alice, she (the Red Queen) has seen gardens so amazing/beautiful/alluring/eye-catching/etc that the garden here is like a wilderness in comparison.

So when the Red Queen says:

> “I could show you hills, in comparison with which you’d call that a valley.”

She's once again showing off. She's seen hills that are bigger and better than the one here, so much so that the hill in front of them would be considered the opposite of a hill. And the opposite of a hill is a valley.

Comment: Yes, by why does she boast using these particular words, especially as, to take your example, there are great differences between the conception of gardens, say French vs English? The French manicured and tightly controlled as many aspects of their gardens as possible, whereas the English let a lot of stuff within their gardens go a bit wild or allowed nature to take its course.

Comment: The entirety of both Alice books mess with the English language and take things to a variety of extremes, and Carroll is very fond of re-using a grammatical pattern in ways that start fairly clear and then extend into the absurd. This seems like a simple demonstration of that.

Answer (score -5):

An argument can be made for the Red Queen’s supposed contradiction.  Notice must be taken of her switch from the singular word “hill” to “hills,” otherwise it becomes somewhat more difficult to understand what she means.  The particularly English term “downs” meaning “hills” (or even mountains) can be found in many dictionaries (see OED, under “Downs” or “Down”).  The “downs” in any other part of the English speaking world probably means, at least in a geographical sense, a lowland or valley. Therefore in this sense the Red Queen may be shown to be right, a “hill/down” or “hills/downs can be a valley!